# Вертикальный собственный SeekBar

Tags: xml, android, java

Добрый день.

Я хочу создать свой вертикальный SeekBar. Для этого я переопределил класс и использовал его в XML.

Но почему-то получаю вот [такую ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GmVA.png).

Java class:

```
package com.example.Radio_KPI.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int i = 0;
                i = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
                setProgress(i);
                Log.i("Progress", getProgress() + "");
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<com.example.Radio_KPI.utils.VerticalSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/volume_bar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
                android:secondaryProgress="0" />
```

Comment: так вам же предлагают собрать проект, в чем проблема то?
вот когда соберете, и запустите - тогда вам и выпадет ошибка, уже от нее плясать надо

Answer (score 1):

Не знаток андроид, но судя по ошибке, Ваше приложение не может загрузить классы, т.е.
1 - библиотека их содержащая, не включена в проект
2 - Вы не правильно к ним обращаетесь, не полное имя(без пакета его содержащего) например.

Answer (score 1):

В общем то эта ошибка влияет лишь на то, что вы не увидите своего бара в визуальном редакторе разметки, на выполнение приложения это никак не влияет. 
[Подробнее по проблеме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419352/177345).

Рекомендую игнорировать, воспользовавшись замечательным крестиком в левом верхнем углу.