# Ошибки в визуальном редакторе Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Мои шаги:

1. Устанавливаю студию с нуля (Ошибок нет).
2. Создаю новый проект с API21 под Android 5.0 с боковой навигацией (Ошибок нет).
3. Создаю еще один проект с API21 под Android 5.0 с боковой навигацией и появляется ошибка отсутствия класса, а именно

> The following classes could not be found:- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Хотя он подключен.

**Переустанавливаю студию** и начинаю заново.
Мои шаги:

1. Устанавливаю студию с нуля (Ошибок нет).
2. Создаю новый проект с API21 под Android 5.0 с боковой навигацией (Ошибок нет).
3. Создаю еще один проект с API21 под Android 5.0 с боковой навигацией и **опять** появляется **ошибка** отсутствия класса, а именно

> The following classes could not be found:- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
>   
>   Хотя он подключен.

В чем смысл? Почему так происходит? Неужели студия не может создать два абсолютно одинаковых проекта без ошибки?

В общем даже не имеет значения какой тип приложения выбираешь из стандартного меню и под какую версию API android делаешь. Все равно высвечиваются ошибки классов или стилей. Сейчас ошибка отсутствия класса `android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout` сразу после создания приложения из шаблона blank activity под android 4.0.3

Заметил что для рендеринга стояла версия API 22, выставил 15 начала появляться ошибка ресурса темы `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode`

В SDK установил все возможные компоненты для API 14, 15, 16, 21 и 22.

Установил все библиотеки от Google, в том числе для Play и т.п.

Но все равно, единственное что создается без ошибок это проект для API21 из шаблона blank activity.

С остальными вариантами всегда ошибки классов или стилей описанные выше. Но даже если в некоторых случаях ошибка не отображается то получается что в рендеринге один вид приложения (цветовая схема светлая) то при отладке по USB на телефоне это же приложение темное будто тема Holo.CompactMenu стоит.

Хотя ни темы HoloLight ни Holo.CompactMenu Android Studio не дает выбрать когда создаешь стиль темы. В файле стилей можно указать тему (естественно с клавиатуры) при наборе, подставляются названия возможных тем. А в файле манифеста уже указана тема из файла стилей. т.е. кастомная тема которая наследует свойства другой темы и можно переопределять стили.

Там только:

- Theme.AppCompact
- Theme.Overlay
- Base.Theme
- Base.v7.Theme
- Base.v21.Theme

И их разные модификации для баров меню и т.п.

Не настолько важно что бы был правильный рендеринг, но если рендеринг выдает ошибку то класс который вызвал ошибку (в частности ActionBarActivity) перечеркивается в самом файле, якобы не доступен. А при компиляции возникают ошибки обработки событий.

Читал на разных форумах что тот же класс android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout работает только на API 22 кто то пишет обратное. По другим темам и классам тоже самое, везде противоречия.

Вопрос:

- Возможно ли вообще создать шаблон приложения для Android 4.0 и выше без ошибок?
- Есть ли где то документация по всем этим классам, где было бы написано какая поддержка API есть в каждом из классов тем и др.?

Comment: Эти ошибки , они у вас в визуальном редакторе что ли , а не при компиляции проекта?

Comment: Да, в визуальном редакторе. А в самом коде перечеркивается класс который выдал ошибку в рендеринге приложения. Тот же ActionBarActivity просто перечеркнут. 

Даже если рендеринг не проходит, приложение все равно компилируется и запускается на телефоне (Проект blank activity с API14). Тест на Galaxy S4, android 5.0 Lollipop при нажатии на левую нижнюю кнопку (меню) само меню не открывается по нажатию, а открывается когда отпускаешь кнопку. т.е. срабатывают по примеру события mouseUp из javacript.

Comment: Пишет:

android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated

This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

Появляется сразу как создаешь чистый проект blank activity для API 15 android 4.0.3 и думаю из за этого ошибка рендеринга в визуальном редакторе. Перечеркнуто прямо в строке создания класса public class index extends ActionBarActivity. Перечеркнуто ActionBarActivity. По поводу визуального редактора, хоть и не критично что визуальный редактор иногда темы не определяет и т.п. Но как то не приятно работать когда сыпятся ошибки.

Comment: Это не ошибка , оно говорит вам , что класс морально устарел и есть более новый , заменяющий его - на это можно просто забить , как и на сообщения визуального редактора , а вообще, скорее всего он хочет , чтобы вы наследовались от AppCompatActivity вместо ActionBarActivity , которая была "придумана" буквально на прошлой неделе и решает ряд проблем , в том числе и с темами. Сэмплы еще не успели обновить , а может и не будут. Названия классов принято писать с большой буквы - Index , а не index

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Может еще подскажете как быть с тем что меню открывается в момент когда отпускаешь кнопку меню, а не нажимаешь? При этом звучит двойной звуковой сигнал, будто два раза кнопку нажал. Как думаете, AppCompatActivity исправит это? А на визуальный редактор получается нужно просто забить и тестировать приложения сразу на эмуляторах или реальном устройстве.

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался , создайте отдельный вопрос по меню , может кто и подскажет . возможно это особенность конкретного устройства

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки рендеринга визульного редактора Android Studio следует решать решительным нажатием на крестик слева вверху , который разработчики предусмотрительно там разместили . Данные сообщения никаким образом не влияют ни на что , кроме как на вид в самом визуальном редакторе и их следует просто игнорировать .
Да, визуальный редактор далек от совершенства , многое в разметке он отобразить не в силах , многое способен запутать так , что диву даешься .
Лучше всего им вообще пореже пользоваться , в основно только для оценки общего вида и подгонки уже сверстанной разметки , изменения аттрибутов и никогда для создания разметки "с нуля" - он там такого наворотит .. дольше исправлять будешь , чем вручную бы сразу написал . чаще пользуйтесь текстовым редактором разметки , чем визуальным.

По теме в визуальном редакторе - в общем то тема , которая отображается в визуальном редакторе никак не связана с темой в самом приложении , которую вы указываете в манифесте и определяете стилями . Тема визуального редактора указывается в самом редакторе , вверху . Это сделано для того , чтобы вы могли быстро оценить , как будет выглядеть экран в разных темах , не меняя ничего в коде .

По собственно вопросам :

1. Безусловно можно , не знаю уж что вы там такое делаете , но до вас , кажется , никто не сталкивался с такими трудностями , как невозможность написать приложение под андроид 4 , не знаю даже , как вам и помочь ..
2. Конечно есть - http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html , тут есть все , что может понадобиться андроид-разработчику , в частности у каждого класса и метода написано с какого API он появился , например `Added in API level 11`

> Хотя ни темы HoloLight ни Holo.CompactMenu Android Studio не дает выбрать когда создаешь стиль темы.

откуда выбрать ? тема приложение указывается в манифесте и пишется на клавиатуре , определяется стилями в приложении и тоже пишется , а не выбирается откуда то ..

PS: не Appcomact , а Appcompat

> класс android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout работает только на API 22

в самом названии написано , что это библиотека поддержки , которая работает начиная от API 4

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Вообще я занимаюсь разработкой сайтов, в частности back-end разработчик и решил попробовать разработать приложение под Android (Клиент для сайта). Но столкнулся с таким количеством толи ошибок Android Studio толи своего не знания в этой области что жуть!


Я даже устанавливал чистую систему Windows на английском языке (что бы на всякий случай не было проблем с кодировкой) но все равно, какой бы проект не пытался создать, опять ошибки рендеринга.

Comment: Заметил еще что даже если рендеринг не проходит, приложение все равно компилируется и запускается на телефоне (Проект blank activity с API14). Тест на  Galaxy S4, android 5.0 Lollipop при нажатии на левую нижнюю кнопку (меню) само меню не открывается по нажатию, а открывается когда отпускаешь кнопку. т.е. событие показа меню срабатывают по примеру события mouseUp из javacript. Но если создать такой же проект но под API21 все нормально.

Comment: Два дня уже потратил пытаясь разобраться с этими ошибками. Кучу форумов пересмотрел. Ни где ничего конкретного. Полтергейст какой-то блин.

Comment: Вы поправили свой ответ. Мой дополнительный комментарий. Когда я написал выбор тему, имелось ввиду что в файле стилей можно указать тему (естественно с клавиатуры) при наборе, подставляются названия возможных тем. А в файле манифеста уже указана тема из файла стилей. т.е. кастомная тема которая наследует свойства другой темы и можно переопределять стили. Так создается стандартное приложение из комплекта студии.